# GitLab CI: Trigger a job when specific files have changed at any commit in a branch

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

I know how to trigger a job in a GitLab CI/CD pipeline when specific files have changed using the `rules` keyword. For example:

```
build_job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Run job"
  rules:
    - changes:
      - src/**/*
```

But that job will only trigger if a file in the specified directory has changed for the current commit. I would like to have that job run if a file in the specified directory has changed at any commit in the branch. Is that possible?

EDIT: I should probably be more specific about my situation. I'm actually using a template job. My `.gitlab-ci.yml` file looks more like this:

```
.build_job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Build $APP"

build-one:
  extends: .build_job
  before_script:
    - APP=one
  rules:
    - changes:
      - src/one/**/*

build-two:
  extends: .build_job
  before_script:
    - APP=two
  rules:
    - changes:
      - src/two/**/*
```

How can I get it to keep building app "one" on each push if a file in `src/one/` changed on the first push but no push after that?

Answer (score 0):

## Edit

After reading the question again and Gitlab's documentation I think you should create a merge request and a unique MR job that will contain the only changes part.
For example:

```
  build-mr:
    extends: .build_job
    before_script:
      - APP=one
    only:
      refs:
        - merge_requests
      changes:
        - src/one/**/*
```

Basing my answer on this doc: [https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#use-onlychanges-with-merge-request-pipelines\](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#use-onlychanges-with-merge-request-pipelines%5C)
Check the example here for the rules method if that is what you prefer: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschanges

## Old answer

If running the job once is good enough, I would suggest running this job only when the pipeline source is a merge request result.
like so:

```
job1:
  script:
    - echo "This job runs in merge request pipelines"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
```

This will happen only after you'll merge the side branch into the target branch.
If the file you are referring to has changed in any commit in the side branch, this job will be triggered.
You'll need to enable the merge result pipeline in the project's settings.
Here are the instruction to do so: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merged_results_pipelines.html#prerequisites 
Another option is to use git diff to check if the file has changed comparing it with the target branch.

```
if git diff --quiet $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME -- file.txt; then
  echo "The file 'file.txt' is identical in both branches."
else
  echo "The file 'file.txt' has differences between the branches."
fi
```

You can use this to trigger the ci job in a downstream pipeline:

```
trigger_job:
  trigger:
    include:
      - local: path/to/job-to-run-when-file-changes.yml
```

Comment: Thank you. Running the job once is not good enough. I'd like it to run for each push to the branch if any files in `src/` have changed at any commit/push in the branch. Not just the most recent push. That Bash conditional would work, but where would I put it? Would this work if I have a template job and other jobs after it that use the `extends` keyword that do the actual checking to see which files have changed?

Comment: Looks like gitlab already enabled the usage of `only: changes` in merge request pipelines.
According the this doc: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#use-onlychanges-with-merge-request-pipelines
"File differences are correctly calculated from any further commits, and all changes in the merge requests are properly tested in pipelines."
This means that if your branch contains changes in these files, the job will run for any MR pipeline comparing it to the target branch.

Comment: I did some testing. That only works when actually submitting a merge request. I would need that job to kick off with every push to the branch as well.

Comment: And I tried using that conditional in a script. That `$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME` variable isn't working. I even have a line to echo that and it shows up blank. So I figured it only exists when a merge request is created. But even then, the build job output doesn't show anything for that variable.

Comment: Yes the `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME` is only available in merge request pipelines.
I am using it in our pipelines and you can refer to this doc for all of the predefined variables - https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html#predefined-variables-for-merge-request-pipelines
Are you sure the pipeline is running from a MR?
You can actually run the pipeline from inside the MR UI, under the pipelines tab.
Anyway it sounds like you need it to run for every push so I am not sure this would help.

Comment: I do see it now. I used the `printenv` command in a job that's triggered by a merge request to see all environment variables. I might have to settle on building only the apps that have changed for the current commit but use that variable to build all that have changed for the MR.